# How to batch convert JPEG images with jpegtran on Windows

Tags: windows, jpeg, command-line-interface, batch-processing, jpegtran

Is it possible to batch convert a folder of JPEG images using jpegtran on Windows?
I normally use the following command for one file, but I'm not sure how to apply it to an entire directory of JPEG files:

```
jpegtran -copy none -optimize a.jpg b.jpg
```

Thank you.

Comment: Seems that not a programming problem, right? Try asking on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/jpegtran).

Comment: [I did just that](http://superuser.com/questions/955916/how-to-batch-convert-jpeg-images-with-jpegtran-on-windows). Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Download jpegtran
2. Put jpegtran.exe in C:/Program Files/Image Optimization (create the folder if it doesn’t exist).
3. Open your text editor, then copy & paste code below.
4. Save it as optimize.bat, then put the file in C:/Program Files/Image Optimization.
5. Run optimize.bat (Run as administrator) to optimize all images in C:/Program Files/Image Optimization (change path in line 3 if you want to optimize another folder).

   `@echo off
   echo Optimizing Images...
   cd "C:\Program Files\Image Optimization"
   forfiles /s /m *.jpg /c "cmd /c @\"C:\Program Files\Image Optimization\jpegtran.exe\" -copy none -optimize -outfile @file @file"
   echo. & echo Process done!
   pause`

The procedure to optimize all images in a folder is described in the following link.
I think it might help you.

[Optimize All Images in a Folder](https://www.thewebflash.com/how-to-optimize-jpeg-png-images-using-jpegtran-optipng-in-windows/)

Answer (score 2):

I found this a bit simpler which works on one line without needing to make a separate batch file. For example if you want to rotate each file by 90:

```
forfiles /s /m *.jpg /c "cmd /c jpegtran -rotate 90 @FILE @FILE"
```

Replace "-rotate 90" with your custom flags for transformation. This script will replace each input file with the transformed output. This assumed jpegtran.exe is in the current directory or system path.